# How to prevent page jump up when open soft keyboard on mobile browser?

Tags: android, jquery, web-applications, mobile-browser

I'm studying mobile web app. How to prevent page jump up when open soft keyboard on mobile browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6111867/969325) is the answer. In short add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your activity tab.

But if you by webapp mean an app that doesn't use any native code I have no idea :)